# Asus RT-N11P Выполнение команды при включении роутера

Tags: linux, asus

Настроил я WakeOnLAN, таблицы ARP в роутере со временнем очищаются и я пишу команду такую `ip neigh change 192.168.1.102 dev br0 lladdr мак nud permanent`  она делает, что в ARP сохраняется запись и она не очищается до перезагрузки. После перезагрузки надо снову водить команду. Как сделать, что бы автоматом писалась команда при загрузки. Роутер Asus RT-N11P

Comment: https://3ddroid.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/577-s235.jpg в кастомной прошивке есть судя по скриншотам такой пункт

Comment: а так попробуй записать в rc.local

Comment: rc.local не существует, а кастомную прошивку ставить не хочется